# rebar3 does not compile anything in `src` directory

Tags: erlang, rebar, rebar3, gleam

I would expect an error to happen or something in the build folder to show up. Here is my `rebar.config`:

```
{plugins, [
    {rebar3_gleam, "1.0.0"}
]}.

{provider_hooks, [
    {pre, [{compile, {gleam, compile}}]}
]}.
```

When I run rebar3 compile, I just see:

```
===> Verifying dependencies...
```

that's it. And no `_build` directory is created :(
I would expect an error, or something to happen....

[image]

I tried, using the DIAGNOSTICS=1 option:

[image]

Still nothing, hot garbage

Comment: Have you tried running with DEBUG=1 or DIAGNOSTICS=1, i.e. `DIAGNOSTICS=1 rebar3 compile` ?

Comment: nope, will try that, but seems like rebar3 should warn user if there is nothing to compile, or whatever, awful experience rn

Comment: I tried that, nothing, see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rebar3 has no support for compiling Gleam. To compile Gleam you'll most likely want to use the Gleam build tool which is built into the `gleam` binary.

Comment: can you show which command to run? rebar3 should still complain if there is nothing to compile. I was under the impression that gleam hooks into rebar3

Comment: Rebar3 has no support for Gleam. If you think it should then you should open a ticket in the rebar3 bug tracker.